# Call PL/SQL procedure by java

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I try to call PL/SQL procedure from Java. This code I use for select/insert values from DB, but when I try to use this query, it just loading without finish. I test this command in SQL Developer and it works.

```
 @Override
public void save(Transactions transactions)
{
    CallableStatement callStmt = null;
    String query = "{CALL CON_API_PKG.createTransaction(?,?,?)}";
    Connection con = null;
    //PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        setDataSource();
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        callStmt = con.prepareCall(query);
        callStmt.setLong(1,transactions.getProductId());
        callStmt.setLong(2, transactions.getReporterId());
        if(transactions.getNote().length() > 0){
            callStmt.setString(3, transactions.getNote());
        }else{
            callStmt.setString(3, null);
        }
        callStmt.executeUpdate();
    /*    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

        ps.setLong(1, transactions.getProductId());
        ps.setLong(2,transactions.getReporterId());
        if(transactions.getNote().length() > 0)
        {
            ps.setString(3, transactions.getNote());
        }
        else ps.setString(3, null);
        int out = ps.executeUpdate();
 */     int out = callStmt.executeUpdate();
        if(out !=0){
            System.out.println("Transaction saved for product_id="+transactions.getProductId());
        }else System.out.println("Transaction save failed for product_id="+transactions.getProductId());
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            callStmt.close();
           // ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No errors? If you let it go on do you get some time of exception or something?

Comment: Without any errors, it just running without end. I updating code right now, but it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use callable statement and use brackets like below

```
CallableStatement callStmt = null;
String query = "{call CON_API_PKG.createTransaction(?,?,?)}";
callStmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
callStmt.setLong(1, 1000);
callStmt.setLong(2, "mkyong");
if(transactions.getNote().length() > 0){
    callStmt.setLong(3, "system");
}else{
    callStmt.setString(3, null);
}
callStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I try it, but it is the same like before.

Comment: Did you use flower brackets { }?

Comment: Yes, I try it with brackets and without brackets.